# When printing string[0] the first letter in each string is the output, not the string in the first row

Tags: python, split

I have a code where I cut each string in my list in half (approximately). Then, for each half I have, I take a random first half and combine it with a random second half. Lastly, I want to call/print each newly made string. For example, in my code, I want print(final[0]) to have an output agray, however, the first letter of it (a) is the output. How do I call each individual row?

```
import random

lis = ['have', 'agreat', 'day']
first = []
second = []
for x in lis:
    first.append(x[:len(x)//2])
    second.append(x[len(x)//2:])
    for x in first+second:
       final = random.choice(first) + random.choice(second)
       print(final)
       print(final[0])
```

output:

```
agray
a
have
h
haeat
h
```

Answer (score 1):

You never put your resulting random words into any list; how do you expect that indexing an individual word will make a list?  In each iteration of your loop, you select random halves, splice them into a new word, print the word, and then overwrite that word on the next iteration.

Let's walk through this in stages.  Taking `lis` as a given item, let's make the two lists of half-words:

```
for x in lis:
    first.append(x[:len(x)//2])
    second.append(x[len(x)//2:])
```

Now, you want each list to be in a random order:

```
random.shuffle(first)
random.shuffle(second)
```

Now, paste your new words together into a new list:

```
final = [left+right for left, right in zip(first, second)]
```

You now have your list of three new words.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using this print might help you to print the whole string as you mentioned.

```
print(final[0:])
```